# C++ - locale name not valid exception when running Moses decoder

Tags: c++, machine-translation, moses

I've successfully compiled Moses (v0.91) on my machine (Windows 7 64-bit) by following the steps described [here](http://www.statmt.org/moses/?n=Development.GetStarted).  However when I try to run it for the first time by running this command in cygwin:

```
cd ~/mosesdecoder/sample-models
~/mosesdecoder/bin/moses -f phrase-model/moses.ini < phrase-model/in > out
```

the following exception occurs:

```
Defined parameters (per moses.ini or switch):
    config: phrase-model/moses.ini
    input-factors: 0
    lmodel-file: 8 0 3 lm/europarl.srilm.gz
    mapping: T 0
    n-best-list: nbest.txt 100
    ttable-file: 0 0 0 1 phrase-model/phrase-table
    ttable-limit: 10
    weight-d: 1
    weight-l: 1
    weight-t: 1
    weight-w: 0
Exception: locale::facet::_S_create_c_locale name not valid
```

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
export LC_ALL="C"
```